# How to add scroll bar to webpage?

Tags: css, scroll, html

I have a webpage built with html and css on which content is being clipped at the bottom of the page. I would like to add scrolling to the page but am unable to do so. I have tried the traditional html{ overflow: scroll;} or html { overflow: auto;} and neither seems to work. I am working with google chrome and have tried it on safari also but the scroll bar never seems to appear. I would like to know what I am missing and would really appreciate any help with making the webpage scroll.

And I am using position: fixed and am not using position: relative, I read somewhere that might make a difference but am hoping against hope that it won't coz I am going to have to change many things if I make that change. Please do let me know whether there is a way to make the webpage scroll with fixed positioning or whether that is the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have posted my code below, I apologize for the very messy code in advance, I am very new to web development:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html
{
    overflow: scroll;
}

th
{
    left:700px;
    top:300px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.first_name_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:330px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.first_name_textbox
{
    left:854px;
    top:330px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.last_name_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:378px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.last_name_textbox
{
    left:854px;
    top:378px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.email_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:426px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.email_textbox
{
    left:854px;
    top:426px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.dob_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:474px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.dob_month_textbox
{
    left:824px;
    top:474px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.dob_day_textbox
{
    left:969px;
    top:474px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.dob_year_textbox
{
    left:1056px;
    top:474px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.sex_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:510px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.loginId_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:550px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.loginId_textbox
{
    left:790px;
    top:550px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.password_text
{
    left:700px;
    top:580px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
td.password_textbox
{
    left:790px;
    top:570px;
    position:fixed;
}
td.confirm_password_text
{
    left:790px;
    top:570px;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(required-field.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
<form name="user_registration_form" metod="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User Registration<th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first_name_text" style="font-size:18px;">Patient First Name</td>
        <td class="first_name_textbox"><input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="30" size="40" style="height:30px;font-size:14pt;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="last_name_text" style="font-size:18px;">Patient Last Name</td>
        <td class="last_name_textbox"><input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="30" size="40" style="height:30px;font-size:14pt;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="email_text" style="font-size:18px;">Patient Email</td>
        <td class="email_textbox"><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" size="40" style="height:30px;font-size:14pt;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="dob_text" style="font-size:18px;">Date of Birth: </td>
        <td class="dob_month_textbox" style="padding-left:2em">Month <SELECT NAME="Month">
            <OPTION SELECTED>January<OPTION>February<OPTION>March<OPTION>April
            <OPTION>May<OPTION>June<OPTION>July<OPTION>August
            <OPTION>September<OPTION>October<OPTION>November<OPTION>December
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
        <td class="dob_day_textbox" style="padding-left:2.5em">Day <Select Name="Day">
            <OPTION SELECTED>1<OPTION>2<OPTION>3<OPTION>4
            <OPTION>5<OPTION>6<OPTION>7<OPTION>8
            <OPTION>9<OPTION>10<OPTION>11<OPTION>12<OPTION>13<OPTION>14<OPTION>15
            <OPTION>16<OPTION>17<OPTION>18<OPTION>19
            <OPTION>20<OPTION>21<OPTION>22<OPTION>23<OPTION>24<OPTION>25<OPTION>26
            <OPTION>27<OPTION>28<OPTION>29<OPTION>30
            <OPTION>31
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
        <td class="dob_year_textbox" style="padding-left:3em">Year <select name="Year"> 
<option value="2012">2012</option> 
<option value="2011">2011</option> 
<option value="2010">2010</option> 
<option value="2009">2009</option> 
<option value="2008">2008</option> 
<option value="2007">2007</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option> 
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2004">2004</option> 
<option value="2003">2003</option> 
<option value="2002">2002</option> 
<option value="2001">2001</option> 
<option value="2000">2000</option> 
<option value="1999">1999</option> 
<option value="1998">1998</option> 
<option value="1997">1997</option> 
<option value="1996">1996</option> 
<option value="1995">1995</option> 
<option value="1994">1994</option> 
<option value="1993">1993</option> 
<option value="1992">1992</option> 
<option value="1991">1991</option> 
<option value="1990">1990</option> 
<option value="1989">1989</option> 
<option value="1988">1988</option> 
<option value="1987">1987</option> 
<option value="1986">1986</option> 
<option value="1985">1985</option> 
<option value="1984">1984</option> 
<option value="1983">1983</option> 
<option value="1982">1982</option> 
<option value="1981">1981</option> 
<option value="1980">1980</option> 
<option value="1979">1979</option> 
<option value="1978">1978</option> 
<option value="1977">1977</option> 
<option value="1976">1976</option> 
<option value="1975">1975</option> 
<option value="1974">1974</option> 
<option value="1973">1973</option> 
<option value="1972">1972</option> 
<option value="1971">1971</option> 
<option value="1970">1970</option> 
<option value="1969">1969</option> 
<option value="1968">1968</option> 
<option value="1967">1967</option> 
<option value="1966">1966</option> 
<option value="1965">1965</option> 
<option value="1964">1964</option> 
<option value="1963">1963</option> 
<option value="1962">1962</option> 
<option value="1961">1961</option> 
<option value="1960">1960</option> 
<option value="1959">1959</option> 
<option value="1958">1958</option> 
<option value="1957">1957</option> 
<option value="1956">1956</option> 
<option value="1955">1955</option> 
<option value="1954">1954</option> 
<option value="1953">1953</option> 
<option value="1952">1952</option> 
<option value="1951">1951</option> 
<option value="1950">1950</option> 
<option value="1949">1949</option> 
<option value="1948">1948</option> 
<option value="1947">1947</option> 
<option value="1946">1946</option> 
<option value="1945">1945</option> 
<option value="1944">1944</option> 
<option value="1943">1943</option> 
<option value="1942">1942</option> 
<option value="1941">1941</option> 
<option value="1940">1940</option> 
<option value="1939">1939</option> 
<option value="1938">1938</option> 
<option value="1937">1937</option> 
<option value="1936">1936</option> 
<option value="1935">1935</option> 
<option value="1934">1934</option> 
<option value="1933">1933</option> 
<option value="1932">1932</option> 
<option value="1931">1931</option> 
<option value="1930">1930</option> 
<option value="1929">1929</option> 
<option value="1928">1928</option> 
<option value="1927">1927</option> 
<option value="1926">1926</option> 
<option value="1925">1925</option> 
<option value="1924">1924</option> 
<option value="1923">1923</option> 
<option value="1922">1922</option> 
<option value="1921">1921</option> 
<option value="1920">1920</option> 
<option value="1919">1919</option> 
<option value="1918">1918</option> 
<option value="1917">1917</option> 
<option value="1916">1916</option> 
<option value="1915">1915</option> 
<option value="1914">1914</option> 
<option value="1913">1913</option> 
<option value="1912">1912</option> 
<option value="1911">1911</option> 
<option value="1910">1910</option> 
<option value="1909">1909</option> 
<option value="1908">1908</option> 
<option value="1907">1907</option> 
<option value="1906">1906</option> 
<option value="1905">1905</option> 
<option value="1904">1904</option> 
<option value="1903">1903</option> 
<option value="1902">1902</option> 
<option value="1901">1901</option> 
<option value="1900">1900</option> 
</select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sex_text" style="font-size:18px;">Sex:</td>
        <td class="sex_radioButtons">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" style="left:766px;top:510px;position:fixed;"><td style="left:788px;top:510px;position:fixed;">Male</td>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"   style="left:834px;top:510px;position:fixed;"><td style="left:856px;top:510px;position:fixed;">Female</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="loginId_text" style="font-size:17px;">Login ID:</td>
        <td class="loginId_textbox">
            <input type="text" name="loginId" maxlength="10" size="25" style="height:28px;font-size:14pt;">
        </td>
        <td class="password_text" style="font-size:17px;">Password:</td>
        <td class="password_textbox">
            <input type="text" name="password" maxlength="25" size="25" style="height:28px;font-size:14pt;">
        </td>
        <td class="confirm_password_text" style="font-size:17px;padding-left:2em" ">Confirm Password:</td>
        <td class="confirm_password_textbox">
            <input type="text" name="confirm_password" maxlength="25" size="25" style="height:28px;font-size:14pt;">
        </td>
 </table>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Fixed is probably your issue, would position:absolute not help you? without seeing code or a link its hard to tell.

Comment: Position fixed is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding an element with property **clear** set to *both* to be the last element in your container that has **position** *fixed*. For example:

```
<div class='fixedDiv'>
    <p> Some element here...</p>
    <p> Another one... </p>
    <a> And a link to somewhere...</a>
    <br class='clear'>
</div>
```

And the css would look like:

```
 .fixedDiv
    {
       position: fixed;
    }

    .clear
    {
       clear: both;
    }
```

If you need to have a div that has to have **position** set to *relative*, you can add another div as a child element to **fixedDiv**. For example:

```
<div class='fixedDiv'>
    <div class='relativeDiv'>
       <p> Some element here...</p>
       <p> Another one... </p>
       <a> And a link to somewhere...</a>
       <br class='clear'>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css would look like:

```
.relativeDiv
{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%; // to consume the whole space from fixedDiv
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Position: fixed` places the elements in question relative to the browser window. I don't think you want to be using this.

Rather, use `position: absolute`, which will allow you in this case to place elements relative to the html element.